# How to inject MassTransit message Headers into my custom class constructor?

Tags: masstransit

I've registered my custom class as `serviceCollection.AddScoped<IMyClass, MyClass>()` to inject it to my Consumer constructor. How can I access message Headers in MyClass constructor on every request?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `ConsumeContext` dependency on MyClass, which will be resolved within the scope of the consumer.

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be added, as i've tried the above, but in the class, i'm getting `{MassTransit.Context.MissingConsumeContext}` instead? This is when using an in memory harness for unit/integration testing.

Comment: @AshleyPoole which version are you using? I tested with MassTransit 7.0.3 and it works as expected.